# Design: Spring Integration jdbc best practice

Tags: spring-integration

After using Spring Integration in a project, my observation is to use jdbc adapter or gateway only at the start or end of the flow. If we use them in the middle of flow then it will become too verbose and complex.

For example:

```
<jdbc:outbound-gateway 
    query="select * from foo where
        c1=:headers[c1] AND
        c2=:headers[c2] AND
        c3=:headers[c3] AND
        c4=:headers[c4]"
    row-mapper="fooMapper" data-source="myDataSource" max-rows-per-poll="100000" />

<int:service-activator ref="serviceActivator" method="processFoo" />
```

In the above `<jdbc:outbound-gateway>`, we need to pass all the placeholders (c1, c2, c3, c4) in the header of Message. We need to look back and forth in java code and xml file for any change in where condition or when there are too many where clauses.

It is also error prone. For example, if we misspelled `:headers[c1]` to `:headers[d1]` then it will not throw any exception and replace `:headers[d1]` with `null`.

If query does not return any row then it will throw exception by default. So, we have to use `requires-reply="false"` to change default behaviour.

If we want to proceed when query does not return any value then we have to add advice to gateway, as shown below:

```
<jdbc:outbound-gateway ... >
    <jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="com.service.NullReplyAdvice" />
    </jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
</jdbc:outbound-gateway>
```

Please correct me if there are flaws in understanding of the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We need to look back and forth in java code and xml file for any change in where condition or when there are too many where clauses.

It's true even for raw Java code around the JDBC: if you change the model you, of course, should change the `SELECT`, because it is just a String. And that's why there is a lot of work to make it type-safe - ORM, QueryDSL, Spring-Data etc.

> if we misspelled :headers[c1] to :headers[d1] then it will not throw any exception and replace :headers[d1] with null.

That's because the `headers` is just a `Map` and it's truth that you get `null`, if there is no such a `key` in the map. To overcome that typo issue you can use POJO `payload` with getters, or some custom header, and again - the POJO with getters. In this case you end up with exception that there is no such a property against object. Although you'll see that issue only at runtime, not on compile. And again the same is with `Hashtable` - only at runtime.

> So, we have to use requires-reply="false" to change default behaviour.

You should understand it at design time: allow or not to return nothing for the component.

The last idea is good. Wouldn't you mind to share your `NullReplyAdvice`?
Actually I achieve the same with `<filter>` before the JDBC gateway: to determine if there is something to fetch by `count(*)` query. From there I can lead my flow to the different logic, rather than the direct flow, when `SELECT` returns rows.

**UPDATE**

When you want to use Model object to keep business-specific values within Message, it's just enough to put this object to the header:

```
public class Foo {

   private String foo1;

   private String foo2;

   public String getFoo1() {
      return foo1;
   }

   public String getFoo2() {
      return foo2;
   }

}

...

MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).setHeader("foo", foo).build();

...

<jdbc:outbound-gateway 
    query="select * from foo where
        c1=:headers[foo].foo1 AND
        c1=:headers[foo].foo2"/>
```

Comment: For NullReplyAdvice implementation, please check http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/125199-issue-with-int-jdbc-outbound-gateway

Comment: My project has too many queries and it has become too verbose now. I have to use NullReplyAdvice after each query to handle null results. Can you please share code of POJO payload with getters. I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: Added POJO header sample

Comment: In the above POJO header sample, how to do routing based on the value of [foo].foo1 . For example, something like this: <int:header-value-router input-channel="routingChannel" header-name=":headers[foo].foo1"> <int:mapping value="X" channel="xChannel" /> <int:mapping value="Y" channel="yChannel" />
 </int:header-value-router>

Comment: No, <header-value-router> just extracts `header` by provided name. For that nested purpose you should use generic router with `expression="headers[foo].foo1"`. Note `:` indicator is just for JdbcTemplate