# Spring Integration: Aggregator is not aggregating splitted messages into one Message

Tags: spring-integration

How to add below flow in the middle of existing Spring Integration flow:

Query from emp table. It returns for e.g. 3 rows. Insert these 3 rows into dept table and then continue the flow as it was running before.

Splitter is configurred manually to implement it. However, flow is not proceeding after `<int:aggregator />` .

emp-context.xml

```
...

<int:splitter apply-sequence="false" /> <!-- parent splitter -->

...

<jdbc:outbound-gateway
    query="SELECT * FROM emp"
    row-mapper="empMapper" data-source="myDataSource"
    max-rows-per-poll="100000" />

<int:service-activator ref="myService" method="process" />

<!--     <int:splitter /> child splitter commented out -->

<jdbc:outbound-gateway
    update="INSERT INTO dept (name, dept)
        VALUES(:headers[name], :headers[dept])"
    data-source="myDataSource" />

<int:aggregator />

<!-- flow is not executed after aggregator -->

<jdbc:outbound-gateway
    update="INSERT INTO other_table (mycol)
        VALUES(:headers[mycol])"
    data-source="myDataSource" />

...
```

MyService.java

```
public List<Message<String>> process(List<EmpRecord> records, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {

    List<Message<String>> result = new ArrayList<Message<String>>();

    UUID correlationId = UUID.randomUUID();
    int sequenceNumber = 0;
    int sequenceSize = records.size();

    for (EmpRecord record : records) {

        msg = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload("null")
            .copyHeaders(headers) // headers contains mycol key that I want to preserve to use after aggregator.
            .setHeader("name", record.getName())
            .setHeader("dept", record.getDept())
            .pushSequenceDetails(correlationId, ++sequenceNumber, sequenceSize)
            .build();

        result.add(msg);
    }

    return result;
}
```

EDIT: added stacktrace.

Please note that headers, class and table names mentioned in the above code are different from the actual implementation. So, I have modified stacktrace as per the above code.

```
06:43:35.171 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing prepared SQL query
06:43:35.171 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT * FROM emp]
06:43:35.171 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcOutboundGateway] handler 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#2$child#0.handler' sending reply Message: [Payload=[com.model.EmpRecord@9a18a0, com.model.EmpRecord@c6e1ec, com.model.EmpRecord@11a5fd0, com.model.EmpRecord@8890da]][Headers={mycol=c1}]
06:43:35.171 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler] ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@1de007d] received message: [Payload=[com.model.EmpRecord@9a18a0, com.model.EmpRecord@c6e1ec, com.model.EmpRecord@11a5fd0, com.model.EmpRecord@8890da]][Headers={mycol=c1}]
06:43:35.171 INFO  [main][com.service.MyServiceActivator] START :: process
06:43:35.171 INFO  [main][com.service.MyServiceActivator] END :: process
06:43:35.171 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler] handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@1de007d]' sending reply Message: [Payload=null][Headers={name=john, dept=BE, mycol=c1}]
06:43:35.171 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcOutboundGateway] org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#2$child#3.handler received message: [Payload=null][Headers={name=john, dept=BE, mycol=c1}]
06:43:35.187 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing prepared SQL update
06:43:35.187 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO dept (name, dept) VALUES(?, ?)]
06:43:35.187 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] SQL update affected 1 rows
06:43:35.187 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcOutboundGateway] handler 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#2$child#3.handler' sending reply Message: [Payload={UPDATED=1}][Headers={name=john, dept=BE, mycol=c1}]
06:43:35.187 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler] org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#2$child#4.handler received message: [Payload={UPDATED=1}][Headers={name=john, dept=BE, mycol=c1}]
06:43:35.187 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler] Handling message with correlationKey [cc7b7fc3-8d7e-bf15-240f-9e893ab7f5cc]: [Payload={UPDATED=1}][Headers={name=john, dept=BE, mycol=c1}]
06:43:35.171 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler] handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@1de007d]' sending reply Message: [Payload=null][Headers={name=john, dept=BE, mycol=c1}]
06:43:35.171 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcOutboundGateway] org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#2$child#3.handler received message: [Payload=null][Headers={name=john, dept=BE, mycol=c1}]
06:43:35.218 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing prepared SQL update
06:43:35.218 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing prepared SQL statement INSERT INTO dept (name, dept) VALUES(?, ?))]
06:43:35.218 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] SQL update affected 1 rows
06:43:35.218 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcOutboundGateway] handler 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#2$child#3.handler' sending reply Message: [Payload={UPDATED=1}][Headers={name=ravi, dept=SE, mycol=c1}]
06:43:35.218 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler] org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#2$child#4.handler received message: [Payload={UPDATED=1}][Headers={name=ravi, dept=SE, mycol=c1}]
06:43:35.218 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler] Handling message with correlationKey [fc91e0bc-87a3-251f-87fd-fc3901285cde]: [Payload={UPDATED=1}][Headers={name=ravi, dept=SE, mycol=c1}]
```

Comment: Switch on the DEBUG logging level for the `org.springframework.integration` category and show here here the logs on the matter.

Comment: Stacktrace added. Please note that primary key violation on other_table is coming because flow after <int:aggregator /> is running multiple times for each splitted record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the root of cause!

Since you return from `MyServiceActivator` the `List<Message<String>>` the `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` determines it as an `Iterable<Message<?>>` and sends them to the `output-channel` one by one. So the `<splitter>` doesn't see anything to split and sends each of them as is - one input message, one output message. From here the `<aggregator>` doesn't see anything to `collect`. That's why it produces several messages for each of input - just because they are in the different `groups`.

To fix your issue you should get rid of `<splitter>` and populate `sequenceDetails` manually:

```
public List<Message<String>> process(List<EmpRecord> records, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {

    List<Message<String>> result = new ArrayList<Message<String>>();

    UUID correlationId = UUID.randomUUID();
    int sequenceNumber = 0;
    int sequenceSize = records.size();

    for (EmpRecord record : records) {

        msg = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload("null")
            .copyHeaders(headers) // headers contains mycol key that I want to preserve to use after aggregator.
            .setHeader("name", record.getName())
            .setHeader("dept", record.getDept())

            .setHeader("correlationId", correlationId)
            .setHeader("sequenceNumber", ++sequenceNumber)
            .setHeader("sequenceSize", sequenceSize)
            .build();

        result.add(msg);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: There is a <splitter> at the start of emp-context.xml flow also. So, on removing this child <splitter> from the flow, the <aggregator> is aggregating the parent splitter. I have updated my question with the parent splitter.

Comment: If you don't need the aggregation of that parent splitter you can switch of it using `apply-sequence="false"`. From other side it looks like you haven't follow with my change to your code. I mean headers for sequence details. However you can use here the useful method - `MessageBuilder#pushSequenceDetails`

Comment: After doing the changes, Splitter is working as expected but flow is not proceeding after <aggregator>. I have updated the code and logs in the question.

Comment: According to your last logs it looks like you haven't compiled the new version of `MyService`: there are no new `correlation` headers. And aggregator just does the stuff against an old value of `correlationId` - for each bunch of records for new JDBC select.

Comment: correlationId is changed but I have not updated it in the question. I cannot disclose project specific details. So manually modifying above logs based on the actual logs generated in the project. I can see sequenceNumber and sequenceSize in the logs. Also, could you please rename service activator to MyServiceActivator in your answer as I have done in the logs. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Answer changed with wish. Do you see the same `correlationId`? Does `INSERT INTO dept (name, dept) VALUES(?, ?)` perform exactly the number of `sequenceSize`? Wouldn't you mind to show the real logs just for the aggregstor? Of course, you can change the message content, but I want to see `sequenceDetails` headers.

Comment: It is working now. sequenceSize was wrongly calculated. However, I am wondering there should be a way to do it without configuring splitter manually. Probably by changing the return type of splitter method.

Comment: That's true. Then you add your business headers before the service-activator and return from the service method just list of your objects, not `List<Message<?>>`. Having that you should revert the `<splitter>` and it will take care about population for you business headers to each splited message.

Comment: Thanks Artem. Could you please also clarify my understanding on SI jdbc design in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448312/design-spring-integration-jdbc-best-practice

Comment: In the manually created sequenceDetails, how shall I handle scenario of no records found in emp query? In the current implementation, null records are inserting into dept table.

Comment: `<filter>` comes to the rescue! In this case it will some `detour` do not insert `null`, but just do anything else, when the payload is an empty `List`